# dlopen: Is it possible to trap unresolved symbols, "manually" resolving them as they happen?

Tags: c, linux, gnu, dynamic-linking, dlopen

Is it possible to trap unresolved symbol references when they happen, so that a function is called to try to resolve the symbol as needed? Or is it possible to add new symbols to the dynamic symbol table at runtime without creating a library file and dlopen'ing it? I am on GNU/Linux, using GCC. (Portability to other Unixes would be nice, but is not a key concern.)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I should have given more detail about what I am trying to do. I want to write an interpreter for a programming language, which is expected to support both compiled (dlopen'ed) and interpreted modules. I wanted calls from a compiled module to functions defined elsewhere to be resolved by the linker, to avoid a lookup for the function at every call, but calls to interpreted code would be left unresolved. I wanted to trap those calls, so that I could call the appropriate interpreted function when needed (or signal an error if the function does not exist).

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish, and what you've got now that isn't working?

Comment: How are you even getting unresolved symbol references? If you're using dlfcn.h, dlsym() returns NULL if it can't find the requested symbol, so perhaps you could use that?

Comment: Interesting question. If you clarify what you're trying to accomplish I'd definitely +1 it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what symbols are missing, you could write a library just with them, and LD_PRELOAD it prior to the application execution.

If you don't have the list of the symbols that are missing, you could discover them by using either 'nm' or 'objdump' on the binary, and, with base on that, write a script which will build the library with the missing symbols prior to the application execution, and then LD_PRELOAD it as well.

Also, you could use gdb to inject new 'code' into applications, making the functions point to what you need.

Finally, you could also override some of the ld.so functions to detect the missing symbols, and do something about them.

But in any case, if you could explain what you are trying to accomplish, it would be easier to provide a proper solution.

Comment: Question edited. Overriding ld.so looks like heavy magic, but might work; I will have a look at this later. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a wild guess that the problem you're trying to address is the case where you `dlopen` and start using a loadable module, then suddenly crash due to unresolved symbols. If so, this is a result of **lazy binding**, and you can disable it by exporting `LD_BIND_NOW=1` (or any value, as long as it's set) in the environment. This will ensure that all symbols can be resolved before `dlopen` returns, and if any can't, the `dlopen` operation will fail, letting you handle the situation gracefully.

Comment: I edited the question to add more information on what I'm trying to do. If I can "handle the situation gracefully" by creating the missing symbol on the fly, this solves the problem.

Comment: I see what you want. There's definitely no way to do this portably. Why are you trying to use native C/asm-level symbols for a higher-level language? If you used your own symbol resolution and binding system, you'd have no problems.

Comment: I thought that it would be simpler to use the existing linker mechanism rather than rolling my own. But it seems that this is the way to go... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Or you can just pass `RTLD_NOW` to `dlopen()` rather than messing with the environment.

Comment: Yeah you really want to use your own mechanism, if for no other reason than to *prevent* C symbols from the host implementation and your interpreter/runtime implementation from leaking to the program you're hosting.